# Parse Object and typescript

Tags: typescript, parse-platform

I building Angular app with Parse Server as a backend. I created `Food` object like this:

```
export class Food extends Parse.Object {
    constructor(){
        super('Food');
        this.set("toto","titi");
    }
}
```

And when i want to create and save Food like this:

```
let food = new Food();
food.set({"nom":"plat 2" , prix:"$10"});
food.save();
```

I always got:

```
error TS2339: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'Food'.
error TS2339: Property 'save' does not exist on type 'Food'.
```

But the object is saved.

NB: When i use the first method presented in documentation: http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#objects, i don't get this error. For example:

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var gameScore = new GameScore();

gameScore.set("score", 1337);
gameScore.set("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.set("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.save();
```

work properly.

How can i properly solve it ?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. Here's a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xq9rg (check the browser console)

Comment: May you try `let food:Parse.Object = new Food();`?

Comment: Thank @fatemefazli, it work fine.